# Is $\frac1{\log x}$ defined at $x = 0$?

Tags: logarithms

Since $\log (x)$ is only defined for $x \gt 0$, then $1/\log (x)$ should only be defined for $x \gt 0$.

However, my graphing calculator says otherwise.

Similarly, would $x\log(x)$, $x/\log (x)$ and $x + \log (x)$ be defined at $x = 0$?

Comment: $1/\log(x)$ is not defined for $x=0$ but $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}1/\log(x)=0$

Comment: Are you familiar with limits? If a function has a limit (even when it's undefined), it will appear to have a value when graphed. In this case, $\lim_{x \to 0^+} 1 / \log(x) = 0$, so the function will appear to have the value $0$ at $x = 0$ when graphed.

Answer (score 1):

$\log (0)$ doesn't exists in any case. And, yes, $\log x$ is well-defined for $x>0$. However, the function
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\log x}$$
is defined for $x>0$ and for the $x$'s such that $\log x \neq 0$, that is, for $x\neq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you calculator use the analytic continuation for $f(x)=\dfrac1{\log x}$ as $$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{\log x}\text{ if } x>0\\
0\text{ if } x=0
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

- $\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{1}{\log x} = 0^-$
- $\lim_{x\to0^+} x{\log x} = 0^-$
- $\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{x}{\log x} = 0^-$
- $\lim_{x\to0^+} x+\frac{1}{\log x} = 0^+$

so you can extend the function even if not defined originaly.